# Checking if Java application has succesfully being started init.d script

Tags: java, spring-boot, systemd, init.d

I have a spring-boot rest sever that is started using an init.d script that is called by systemd. Once the server is started it is considered successful by the the script. This leads to problems such as if the sever fails for a reason such as port already in use it will still be considered to have succeeded. I have come up with a solution that greps the log files last few line in a loop to make sure nothing has gone wrong and returns an error if it has but I feel this has the potential to introduce race conditions and could lead to unexpected behavior. Is there a better approach to this that could be used?

Answer (score 0):

u can add something like below to ur script, which copies(>) all the output of the script trigger to a file and from which grep for ERROR

"command to trigger script" >dump.txt
findstr /I "ERROR" dump.txt

where "findstr" finds the string, "I" stands for case insensitive and customize ur error string u need to search

Comment: Not sure this will work, I am already redirecting the output to the log file. Could always tee the file and grep that I suppose

Comment: Then just use  findstr /I "ERROR" dump.txt

Comment: It appends to the end of the log file, so if there is a error from a previous run it will pick that up when it shouldn't

Answer (score 0):

You can ask systemd for the status of your application:

```
 $ systemctl status your-app
```

Or you could use `is-active`:

```
$ systemctl is-active your-app
```

The exit code will be 0 if your application is active, and something other than 0 if it is not active.